# How to Extend a regression line and customize the axis ticks in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got the following data:

```
vpri=seq(2,16,2)
vfb = 1.87*vpri
```

I want to make a linear regression that goes out from vfb = 1 to 100 on the y axis.
I've tried a few things and wound up with this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=vpri, y=vfb)) +geom_point(shape=1) +
  xlim(0,60) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",fullrange = TRUE) +          
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,5))
```

However, the truth is that the value of 60 I have in the arugments for `xlim` is something I got only after guessing and checking.

I would like to get the `stat_smooth` object to treat the y axis as the judge of what '`fullrange`' really is, not the x axis.  furthermore, once I get this far, I would then need to add custom tick-spacing to both axes (since the 25/division is too coarse) , but I know that R will throw a fit when I use `xlim` (or `ylim`) as the thing to drive `stat_smooth` and then ask it to handle the ticks later on with a `scale_x_continuous`, or a `scale_y_continuous`

Answer (score 1):

This did it:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=vpri, y=vfb)) +geom_point(shape=1) +    # Use hollow circles
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,60),breaks=seq(0,60,5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,2*60,5)) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",fullrange = TRUE)
```